# react > i18n not working after switching from yarn to pnpm

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I have a monorepo based on react + typescript
We are recently trying to change the package manager from yarn to pnpm.

After changing few codes the build / run are all fine
But the i18n is not working > it shows the key itself, not the translated word.

that is, if we use `t('somekey')` -> `someKey` itself is displayed. (translation not working)

And displays the warning
`utils.js:11 react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next`

and
`utils.js:11 react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using i18nextReactModule`

we're using
react-i18next 12.2.0 and i18next 22.0

i18n is initialized at the beginning of the whole application
and it works fine when installed & run through yarn.

I tried `pnpm dedupe` as this repo suggests https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOT.md but still not working.

any of you guys know why or how can we fix this?

It's some of the codes we use to init i18n.

```
const i18nInstance = i18n.createInstance().use(initReactI18next)

i18nInstance.init({
  lng: 'ko-KR',
  react: {
    useSuspense: false,
  },
})

export function initI18n(config: I18nModuleConfig) {
  const { lng = Language.KO_KR, debug = false, translation, saveMissing, missingKeyHandler } = config
  const initInstance = i18nInstance.init({
    lng,
    debug,
    fallbackLng: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    resources: {
      [lng]: translation,
    },
    saveMissing,
    missingKeyHandler,
  })
  return initInstance
}
```